# Node.js application starts never ending processes in production

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I am hosting a node.js application on cPanel. It is nothing but simple RESTful web APIs using express which include CRUD. The issue that I am facing is that the number of processes are getting increased by time, means some of the previous processes are never ending and application keeps on adding until the point where my server reaches resource limit and all the applications stop working.

cPanel actually doesn't have a way to `console.log()` any errors which I am writing the code to do from inside my application. All I can see is the main domain from where the processes are stemming.

I tried to write my own log file for that but that didn't help too

I am writing this in my terminal to check processes `ps -ef | grep node` (because I know all the processes are only node.js processes). I noticed that the number of processes I can see in this command are different (way less) than that I can see in side my cPanel dashboard!

**UPDATE:**

For an example, this is one of the APIs which is creating issue:

**My `app.js` (entry point)**:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Initialize the app
const app = express();

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
 
// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' })
 
// setup the logger
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream }))

// Parse the body to JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serving static files
app.use("/images", express.static("images"));

// Routes middlewares go here!
app.use("/api/categories", require("./routes/category-routes"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/user-routes"));
app.use("/api/sellers", require("./routes/seller-routes"));
app.use("/api/services", require("./routes/service-routes"));
app.use("/api/resellers", require("./routes/reseller-routes"));
app.use("/api/support", require("./routes/support-routes"));
app.use("/api/trackings", require("./routes/tracking-routes"));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  res
    .status(500)
    .send({ success: false, error: err, errors: ["Something went wrong"] });
});

// Start listening finally
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    // .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI_NAI_NAI_NAI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(() => {
      console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    try {
      fs.appendFileSync("my-own-log-file.txt", `\n\n${err}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    process.exit(1)
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**Here I am registring the route:**

```
// @route   POST /api/services/filtered-by-state
// @desc    To fetch all services filtered by state
// @access  public

router.post(
  "/filtered-by-state/",
  body("state")
    .trim()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage("Please enter choose a state"),
  checkValidity,
  serviceControllers.getServicesFilteredByState
);
```

**This is the controller:**

````
exports.getServicesFilteredByState = (req, res) => {
  let page = req.query.page || 1;
  const { state, sellerId } = req.body;
  let options = {};

  if (page) {
    page = parseInt(page);
  }

  if (state === "Australia Wide") {
    options = { state }; // Look for only documents where state is 'Australia wide'
  } else {
    // Look for documents where state is 'Australia wide' or ```state``` itself
    options = { state: { $in: ["Australia Wide", state] } };
  }

  if (!sellerId) {
    options.isHidden = false;
  }

  let totalItems = 0;

  Service.find(options)
    .countDocuments()
    .then((numServices) => {
      totalItems = numServices;
      return Service.find(options)
        .sort("sortingOrder")
        .populate("sellerId")
        .populate("categoryId");
      // .skip((page - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
      // .limit(ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
    })
    .then((foundServices) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        totalItems,
        services: foundServices,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).status("Something went wrong");
    });
};
````

This is simple CRUD!

Comment: Have you tried to run the application using for example pm2? It automatically writes a log  which might be helpfull in your case

Comment: thanks for your advice, I actually started my app with pm2 but I don't exactly know where can I check how many processes this specific applications has. it shows me some basic stuff like cpu mem usage and uptime etc, Could you please help me how can I check the number of processes of my application?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how number processes increases exactly. Is it that they aren't getting killing during restarts or they are just spawning randomly? My expectation is that a simple RESTful API shouldn't really be spawning any new processes after being started itself.

Comment: @TayyabFerozi can you share a screenshot of the process that you have created and the processes that have increased

Comment: @aRvi When I asked their support team about how they define `number of processes` they replied: "A process is a computation that your computer makes so the number of processes would be the number of computations your computer can make at the same time". Here are the images you want: https://imgur.com/a/4xQp5AB

Comment: @glock18 Yes, thats what I myself can't figure out, also I can't get more logs than that. I think the processes increase when I start making HTTP requests on the application (access those APIs). But each route on my application is return something (this means the request is ended by giving a success or error response to the user). So how come those processes never end. Really stuck!

Comment: Processes that you are seeing in the cPanel dashboard are the concurrent processes that are going on at that time. And the process that you see in `ps -ef | grep node` are the actual pm2 instances that you have created.

Comment: But I don't know where are these processes stemming from actually, they never end and when they reach limit I can't don anything on my server, all my applications also stop working. This is the actual problem.

Comment: @aRvi I am not using pm2 on my production server, and I started the application only once, why are their more than one instances of the same application??

Comment: can you show the CRUD code pls ?

Comment: @TayyabFerozi apart of pm2 do you use any other application persistence apps like forever, supervisord, etc.? I'm afraid we are gonna need much more information to help you. For start, give a more accurate information on how many CPU cores you have and how many node processes can be running at the same.

You mentioned, that you aren't able to write any logs, but seeing that you are able to run shell commands via cPanel, I'd try finding anything you wrote. Perhaps you've been looking in a wrong place.

Comment: @TayyabFerozi also you seem to be contradicting yourself in regards to pm2. In one of the first comments you mentioned that you use pm2, and when you replied to aRvi you said that you don't use it

Comment: @glock18 No no, I donot use pm2, after receiving the first reply by Bogdan Stoica, I tried pm2 to track down the issue but didn't find it useful. That was the first time I used pm2 in my life

Comment: And yes I am using [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) (instaed of pm2) which keeps track of code and restarts the server automatically when I change anything in my code.

Comment: I have this in my `package.json` under `"scripts"`: `"start": "nodemon app.js,"`. And here in this part of my cPanel: https://imgur.com/ajvIJJ6, I can clearly see the button to run JS scripts which I never used (means I have never run `start` script too) which could lead to a _never ending process_!

Comment: I don't know you guys noticed this or not that for each of my `PIDs` (which I get on running `ps -ef | grep node` or all the **`node.js`** processes on running `ps aux`) for each of them I have exactly 10 _never ending processes_ in my cPanel dashboard! Why exactly 10 processes for each process? 

Comment: I noticed a similar thing indeed when using htop. Although top doesn't show any more than 1 per a process. Not sure why, but perhaps it is somehow related to node.js core using a pool of threads internally (see Jesus Aguas answer for explanation).

According to your screenshots though, you have a 75 process limit, and you only use 1 application (is it correct?). So, even if each one is counted for 10, it still shouldn't be a problem with a single process running?

Comment: @glock18 No man, The point is that these donot remain 10 processes. They keep on increasing and add 10 more each time on approximately every request. If it would have remained 10 processes for one node.js application, it wouldn't be a problem for me. But after some time 10 more processes are added, then again 10 more until they reach the limit and all the applications break. It doesn't matter whether I have one application or two. All of them keep on increasing the processes!

Comment: It sounds like you have a new process started on a request. Clearly an issue with the application or/and environment. You are gonna have to post logs (you have access to the shell via cPanel, you just need to figure out how to access logs from there) and the code. There is nothing we can do for you without them.

Comment: @Aion Please see the updated question

Comment: @glock18 I can see a file named `sterr.log` which has a bunch of these lines: `node[<some number which is different each time (I guess it's the process ID)>]: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable`. BUT, I think this is not related to the problem I am facing because I requested my application API again after clearing this file and in the terminal I could see the processes but the `sterr.log` was still empty. So I think it has nothing to do with this problem. Maybe it is generated when cPanel couldnot start application because of reaching memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

A Node.js application runs on single thread and the event loop also runs on the same thread. So we can say that Node.js is single-threaded but the catch is that there are some libraries in Node.js that are not single-threaded.

Node.js internally uses the **libuv** library which is responsible for handling operating system related tasks, like asynchronous I/O based operation systems, networking, concurrency, etc.
Libuv sets up a thread pool of x threads to perform OS-related operations by utilizing the power of all the CPU cores. For example, if you have a computer with 4 CPU cores, Libuv will create a thread pool of 4 threads, each thread from the pool is assigned to every core. This results in one thread per core.

However, you can change this value by changing the UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE environment variable:

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = numOfThreads;
```

In case you are not doing anything wierd with your code, this is totally normal for Node.js and will use as many CPU cores as available to perform better.

I have found a really interesting article that explains everything in detail:
[Is Node.js Really Single-Threaded?](https://medium.com/better-programming/is-node-js-really-single-threaded-7ea59bcc8d64)

Comment: To be honest, I don't think OP meant threads in his question.

Comment: Actually I can't get whats actually happening in my server. If this was an issue with these threads, process should automatically be finished when the async task is completed. Why does it keep on running forever? If you know a condition where it could happen, please let me know. If my problem is fixed I will surely start the bounty again to reward the answerer, Thanks for your answer

Comment: Without any code, or any script where we can see if you do something wrong when starting the processes we can't help much. I have found a forum for cpanel issues where you might find answers or at least something that can make clearer where the problem is at: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/entry-process.667557/